# K8s PVC: obtain the utilization state of PCV

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I'm working on a k8s namespace environment and I have a pod and its pvc deployed in it.
When the pod transfers data on PVC I would know the percentage of memory used and free.
There is a way?

Comment: If your pod container has a shell, simply `kubectl exec` into the container's shell and execute a `df -h`. The PVC mount path should be listed by the command.

Comment: Are you using `kubeadm`, `minikube` or `Managed Kubernetes Service` ?

Comment: @matt_j I'm working on a KaaS, so I'm using kubectl.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [kubedf](https://gist.github.com/redmcg/60cfff7bca6f32969188008ad4a44c9a) (it supports most KaaS) script to show PVC usage. It only requires `kubectl proxy` to be running.

---

I will create an example to illustrate how it may work.

First, we need to download this script:

```
$ wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/redmcg/60cfff7bca6f32969188008ad4a44c9a/raw/e5c5722e7b4a5725afe9217ebd05fb33a11d4571/kubedf

$ ls
kubedf

$ chmod a+x kubedf
```

After a successful installation, we nee to run `kubectl proxy`:

```
$ kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

And from another terminal window, we can test how it works. I have two `PV` and `PVC`:

```
$ kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM               STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-52db08b6-dbb0-4fd7-b5a3-f828bf83f5c5   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/myclaim-2   standard                33m
persistentvolume/pvc-db341238-8e7c-425c-856d-546589fa8c69   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/myclaim     standard                43m

NAME                              STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/myclaim     Bound    pvc-db341238-8e7c-425c-856d-546589fa8c69   1Gi        RWO            standard       43m
persistentvolumeclaim/myclaim-2   Bound    pvc-52db08b6-dbb0-4fd7-b5a3-f828bf83f5c5   1Gi        RWO            standard       33m
```

Let's use `kubedf` to show PVC usage:

```
$ ./kubedf -h
PVC       Size Used Avail Use%
myclaim   974M 101M  858M  10%
myclaim-2 974M 301M  658M  31%
```